# WooCommerce: Name of short description meta field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I want to populate the short description field of a WooCommerce product with Gravity Forms.
Unfortunately I couldn't figure out the name of the meta field(?).

Every other meta field works fine. I've checked the code and some docs to find the correct name but I couldn't find it.

I tried the following: `excerpt`, `postexcerpt`, `post_excerpt`.
In the backend code the field's name is `excerpt`. To use the field's name works for every other meta field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet will make the short description / excerpt show up as a mappable field:

```
add_filter( 'gform_advancedpostcreation_excerpt', 'enable_excerpt', 10, 1 );
function enable_excerpt( $enable_excerpt ){
    return true;
}
```

https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_advancedpostcreation_excerpt/#examples

Answer (score 0):

The great support over at Gravity Forms pushed me in the right direction.
You have to use a custom snippet to map the form field with short description / excerpt:

```
add_action( 'gform_advancedpostcreation_post_after_creation', 'update_product_information', 10, 4 );
function update_product_information( $post_id, $feed, $entry, $form ){

    //update the excerpt
    $the_post = array(
        'ID'           => $post_id,//the ID of the Post
        'post_excerpt' => $entry['60'],
    );
    wp_update_post( $the_post );

}
```

Here you can find some more informations: https://docs.gravityforms.com/advanced-post-creation-add-on-using-third-party-post-types/#handling-fields-unable-to-be-mapped-2